# Fallback options for private DNS servers

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I have a private DNS server that is used across locations, configured on routers and on mobile devices. For routers, it uses the IP for DoH/DoTLS. For mobile devices, it uses the domain "dns.example.com". We rent the server from the data center and have no infrastructure other than the server itself.

Yesterday the data center that hosts the server experienced outages that caused it to go offline. All the routers use a secondary DNS IP, but mobile devices that use the domain were having connectivity issues.

What would be the best way for me to set up the domain to fall back to a secondary IP should the first node go down? I would like to put a fallback server in a different location. I know you can use multiple A records for the domain, but from my understanding it is not a reliable way to do it since the initial query will only return one of the IPs, regardless of the status of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest anycast DNS service. Be it homegrown (which requires dedicated address space and some BGP knowledge) or by 3rd party (some DNS providers offer secondary servers on anycast addresses).

Cloudflare provides DNS anycast services for free, but it does not include slave servers. If you don't mind management thorugh web interface it may be workable solution. Or maybe paid account provides secondaries.

Please note - this is just an example, there are other options.